# How to iterate an array from parent componenent form in angular (reactive forms)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

As the title says, I'm looking for a way to iterate an array (addresses) from parent component dynamically on child component using reactive forms.

As it is now I don't get any errors but it doesn't display anything.

I feel like I'm fumbling a bit in the dark so any help would be much appreciated.

**Parent Component:**

company-profile.component.ts

```
CreateForm(): void {
    console.log('createFrom:');
    this.companyProfileForm = this.fb.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      registrationNumber: null,
      webAddress: '',
      description: '',
      addresses: this.fb.array([this.createAddress()])
    });
  }

  createAddress(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      address: '',
      postCode: '',
      city: '',
      countryId: null,
    });
  }

 populateForm(): void {
  console.log('populateForm: Populating form from companyId: ' + this.company.id);
   this.companyProfileForm.reset({
    title: this.company.title,
    registrationNumber: this.company.registrationNumber,
    webAddress: this.company.webAddress,
    description: this.company.description,
    addresses: this.company.addresses
  });
}
```

company.profile.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="company" class="row">
        <app-company-profile-address [addresses]="companyProfileForm.controls['addresses']"></app-company-profile-address>
 </div>
```

**Child Component**

company-profile-address.component.ts

```
constructor(
@Inject(forwardRef(() => CompanyProfileComponent))
public companyProfileComponent: CompanyProfileComponent,
private companyService: CompanyService,
) {}
```

company-profile.address.componenet.html

```
<div [formGroup]="addresses">
```

```
<div formArrayName="addresses" *ngFor="let address of companyProfileComponent.companyProfileForm.get('base.addresses'); let i = index;">

  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <legend>Address</legend>
    <div class="form-group" aria-required="">
      <label for="postalAddress">Postal address</label>
      <input formControlName="address" type="text" id="postalAddress" value="address.address" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="postCode">Post code</label>
          <input formControlName="postCode" type="text" id="postCode" value="address.postCode" class="form-control">
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="city">City</label>
          <input formControlName="city" type="text" id="city" value="address.city" class="form-control">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: adding to my answer below, this might be a good start to understand nested forms, it's not exactly what you need for this question, but it will give you an idea of how to populate a FormArray: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2#toc-part-2-move-address-to-a-new-component

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the way you populate your FormArray.

```
populateAddress() {
  const control = <FormArray>this.companyProfileForm.controls['addresses'];

  this.company.addresses.forEach(element => {
    control.push(element);
  })
}
```

you need to create a *FormArray* , but you are passing an array of objects into your formGroup.

*Also you have got a typo in component name: *company-profile.address.componen**e**t.html*

Hope this helps